# Why does the goroutine only run once as part of a waitgroup

Tags: go, goroutine

```golang
func check(name string) string {
    resp, err := http.Get(endpoint + name)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return string(body)

}

func worker(name string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, names chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    var a = check(name)
    names <- a
}

func main() {
    names := make(chan string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker("www"+strconv.Itoa(i), &wg, names)
    }
    fmt.Println(<-names)
}
```

The expected result would be 5 results but, only one executes and the process ends.
Is there something I am missing? New to go.
The endpoint is a generic API that returns json

Comment: You are missing the wg.Wait.

Comment: @Volker wg.Wait will deadlock unless all values are read from the channel

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem I was having when my friend suggested that.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I didn't say adding wg.Wait would fix all problems this code has. all I stated was that wg.Wait is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are launching 5 goroutines, but are reading from the `names` channel only once.

```
fmt.Println(<-names)
```

As soon as that first channel read is done, `main()` exits.
That means everything stops before having the time to be executed.

To know more about channels, see "[Concurrency made easy](https://github.com/robphoenix/concurrency-made-easy)" from [Dave Cheney](https://twitter.com/davecheney/status/868442647857209345):

> - If you have to wait for the result of an operation, it’s easier to do it yourself.
> - Release locks and semaphores in the reverse order you acquired them.
> - Channels aren’t resources like files or sockets, you don’t need to close them to free them.
> - Acquire semaphores when you’re ready to use them.
> - Avoid mixing anonymous functions and goroutines
> - Before you start a goroutine, always know when, and how, it will stop

Answer (score 3):

You started 5 goroutines, but read input for one only. Also, you are not waiting for your goroutines to end.

```
// If there are only 5 goroutines unconditionally, you don't need the wg
for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        go worker("www"+strconv.Itoa(i),  names)
}
for i:=1;i<=5;i++ {
   fmt.Println(<-names)
}
```

If, however, you don't know how many goroutines you're waiting, then the waitgroup is necessary.

```
for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
      wg.Add(1)
      go worker("www"+strconv.Itoa(i), &wg, names)
}
// Read from the channel until it is closed
done:=make(chan struct{})
go func() {
   for x:=range names {
     fmt.Println(x)
    }
    // Signal that println is completed
    close(done)
}()

// Wait for goroutines to end
wg.Wait()
// Close the channel to terminate the reader goroutine
close(names)
// Wait until println completes
<-done
```

Comment: That only prints 4?

Comment: Because the program terminates before the last fmt.Println completes.